# The Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: ''<URL>''. It will be ignored

Tags: php, content-security-policy

The project use CSP to enhance the security.

But when set list, the page always show error message, and any plugin can't load, such as google chart.

[image]

The project setting:

[image]

I try different browser, such as Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Opera and Safari, the page plugin can't load.

Why this problem happened? How could I do to resolve it.

Comment: Are you using an `iframe`?

Comment: No. I used `$('iframe')` to find `iframe`. There were  no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#sources for which sources should and should not have single quotes. You must remove single quotes from URLs. In most cases you could also omit https:// leaving only the hosts in the source list.